# I specifically want to delete my grep output string from the text file

Tags: linux, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I specifically want to delete my grep output string from the text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50326/i-specifically-want-to-delete-my-grep-output-string-from-the-text-file)

I'm a little bit new with Linux and I have a problem. 
I have a text file called `file_a.txt` My first 
command

`grep -A 12 ".production =" file_a.txt`

The output is a few block. Each block of string contains 13 rows

I specifically want to delete all the block of strings I got with the `grep` 
command from the original file `file_a.txt` I do not want to send the grep 
output to a new file. Also I do not want to to use `grep -v` because it will not work in my case.

I have tried something like things like this, but nothing is working:

`cut < grep -A 12 ".production =" file_a.txt`

`sed -i '/grep -A 12 ".production ="/d' file_a.txt`

Comment: what happened with my answer???

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad no deleted answer showing up, so you/the browser probably didn't successfully post it. I checked, you didn't post at the wrong question (at least on [SO])

Comment: @Clayton please don't cross post, as a Unix SE moderator I'm requesting this be closed here and moved there.

Comment: @xenoterracide huh. Why didn't you cast a close-vote (offtopic, SU) then? Also, this is entirely appropriate for [SO] IMO. There is a certain amount of overlap, as shell scripting is considered programming too

Comment: @sehe note SU is not Unix, and it is appropriate but cross posting is frowned upon. we really don't need people posting a verbatim copy of the same question on SO, SU, SF, AU, and U&L (within 10 minutes) just so they can get points or a faster answer. I didn't vote to close offtopic because it's technically? not. I think there ought to be rules about crossposting and flag as cross site duplicate... but it's a pipe dream.

Comment: @xenoterracide I can agree with everything you've said there. Has anything like this ever been proposed on meta?

Comment: yes I know I brought it up. Don't ask me where.

Comment: @xenoterracide I didn't merge since these answers are duplicates of one on the other post. This whole comment thread should go at some point

Comment: @MichaelMrozek that's cool

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for this:

```
sed -i '/.production =/,+12d' file_a.txt
```

When sed finds you patterns it "deletes" 12 lines

(warning, modifies file_a.txt *in-place*)

Comment: Except the next 12 rows need to be deleted as well.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams whoops, added

Comment: @sehe +1 for fast posting and editing ! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i '/\.production =/,+12d' file_a.txt
```

would do the job